# 'The floating point value '5E884898' is out of the range of computer representation (8 bytes).'

Tags: c#, sql-server, forms, hash

I am trying to check login details from a database and getting this error. I somewhat understand what it means and am just trying to see if theres anyway around it? I am using sha256 to hash the passwords and then checking username and password against the database.

Here is the code:

```
        static string hashPassword(String password)
        {
        
            string hashedResult = "";
            using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                byte[] hashedValue = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
                foreach (byte h in hashedValue)
                {
                    hashedResult += $"{h:X2}";
                }
            }
            return hashedResult;
        }
        
        bool loginCheck(string userLogin, string hashedPassword)
        {
            connection.Close();
            connection.Open();
            string loginCheck = $"SELECT userPassword from logins WHERE userName = {userLogin} AND userPassword = {hashedPassword}"; //creates an sql query to execute
            List<String> users = new List<string>();
            using (SqlCommand loginChecker = new SqlCommand(loginCheck, connection))

            {
                SqlDataReader myReader = loginChecker.ExecuteReader();
                while (myReader.Read()) // loops to add all values read to a list.
                {
                    users.Add(myReader["userName"].ToString());
                }
            }
            if (users.Count == 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;

        }
```

this is the simple sql table:

```
CREATE TABLE logins (
loginID INT PRIMARY KEY iDENTITY (1,1),
userName varchar(255),
userPassword varchar(255),
priorityLevel int
)
```

an example of what is being put in:
userName = test
password = E7CF3EF4F17C3999A94F2C6F612E8A888E5B1026878E4E19398B23BD38EC221A

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is **dangerous**. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: Not to mention that *if* you got to the point of executing the SQL, with the parameters you define in your question, you would likely get the errors *"Invalid column name 'test'."* & *"Invalid column name 'E7CF3EF4F17C3999A94F2C6F612E8A888E5B1026878E4E19398B23BD38EC221A'."*

Comment: @Larnu is this correct? ```var usernameParameter = new SqlParameter("userLogin", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    usernameParameter.Value = userLogin;
    var passwordParameter = new SqlParameter("hashedPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    passwordParameter.Value = hashedPassword;
    loginChecker.Parameters.Add(usernameParameter);
    loginChecker.Parameters.Add(passwordParameter);

Comment: `Text` is certainly not the right data type; that data type has been deprecated since **2005**. Based on your question, you should be using `VarChar` for your `SqlDbType` with a length of `255`.

Comment: There are no floats in the code. Post the actual full exception text. The location and more importantly, the stack trace will show where the error occurred. BTW this kind of hashing is trivially easy to crack even with brute force calculations. You need to use salting *AND* a cryptographically safe hashing algorithm *AND* repeat hashing for a *lot* of times. The built-in [PasswordDeriveBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes?view=net-7.0) class uses at least 1000 iterations but nowadays 10K is the recommended minimum

Comment: @Larnu yeah i just realised and changed to varchar

Comment: Hashes are binary anyway. There's no reason to store them as text. What you need is a `varbinary` field, not `varchar`. That won't result in a float error though.

Comment: Because you inject values into your sql command, you get a "5E884898" there that is interpreted as `5 * 10^884898`, which is way above the limit for a floating point value

Comment: @Larnu, adding in the parameters and changing users.Add(myReader.ToString()); seems to have worked. Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to roll your own account storage? ASP.NET has secure database account storage since 2001, which properly salts and hashes passwords. The algorithms have changed from one version to the other but they're always more secure than hand-rolled code. In ASP.NET Core this is provided by the `Individual` authentication option in the project template

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos need to have a database and hash/encryption for college project, so thought it would help to get more stuff in for marks

Comment: `seems to have worked` it hasn't, it only replaced one bug for another. `users.Add(myReader.ToString());` doesn't return the first item as a string, it calls `Object.ToString()` which returns the type name, eg `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader...`

Comment: @CharlieGale database and hash storage are already available out of the box

Comment: If you need hashing and/or encryption just for marks, don't do any of these on passwords. There is just too much you can do wrong. You want to show hashing: find something that's not cryptographically relevant. And for encryption passwords are out the window anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, you have many serious issues.

- **Your primary issue:** you are not parameterizing your query, so SQL Server is misinterpreting the hash as a number.
- Using raw `varbinary(32)` for the hash, and passing as `SqlDbType.VarBinary, 32` would be more efficient.
- You should salt your password before hashing, to prevent rainbow table attacks.
- Do not cache connection objects. Create when needed, dispose with `using`.
- `SqlDataReader` also needs to be disposed.
- There is no need to return the hash back to the client. Just return `SELECT 1` and check in the client if there was a matching row.
- Consider using `async` `await`.

```cs
bool loginCheck(string userLogin, string hashedPassword)
{
    const string loginCheck = @"
SELECT 1
from logins l
WHERE l.userName = @userLogin
  AND l.userPassword = @hashedPassword;
"; //creates an sql query to execute
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(YourConnString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(loginCheck, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@userLogin", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = userLogin;
        command.Parameters.Add("@hashedPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = hashedPassword;
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var isValid = myReader.Read();    // was there at least one row?
            return isValid;
        }
    }
}
```